# Workflow to copy data from a Rich Text Field to a Text Field (Multi-line)

Tags: infopath, forms-services, rich-text, multiline-text-field

I tried using a workflow that will copy data from a rich text field to a text field (with multi-line enabled) in a online-based infopath form but without success.

Are there other ways to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, one need to setup the infopath field by check the `Allow users to edit data in this field by using a datasheet or properties page` checkbox and publish it.

After publish it, modify that field from single line to multiple line and that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a rule on the text field to equal the rich text field when it is not blank.